# how to show open/save dialog when linking to pdf files

Tags: html, pdf

I'm trying to link a pdf document from a static html file.

What I'm using is:

```
<a href="some_pdf_file.pdf">My pdf File</a>
```

the open/save dialog comes up in firefox but not in IE7 or IE8.

I believe I have to change the MIME type but I don't know where to change it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it works in Firefox I assume the file is actually there and accessible. In that case it depends on the browser settings how the download is handled. It might be that the download happens in the background because you setup that it should automatically download everything into a predefined folder (e.g. My Downloads/).

Check the IE settings to see where it puts downloads and check the folder to see if downloaded the file.

Comment: in IE when I click the link it right away opens the PDF right there in the same window rather than showing me the open/save dialog box first.

Comment: This is most likely because of an Adobe Reader setting. Open the application (e.g. "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"), go to "Edit > Preferences" and find the category "Internet". There should be an option "Display PDF in browser" at the top. If you uncheck it Adobe Reader won't be used anymore and IE will probably show you a download dialog box instead.